# Database creating. Additional column or additional table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I'm developing a server for a multilanguage application(russian and english). All text will be stored in one table, text will be have russian and english version. At start, almost all text will not have english version. I see two solutions:
1) Store in different columns russian and english versions of a text(will be many nulls).
2) Store in first column a text and language id in second column. Then i will needed one more table, which will be stored text groups(for example, text "Vodka" and "Водка" is one text group, but have different language id).

One user will be use only one language. Which of these solutions is better from performance point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes a big difference performancewise, but the text table with only one text column has the advantage of being dynamic. I.e. if you add a third language one time, your queries don't have to be altered.

Text columns per language:

```
select
  (select case when :lang = 'RU' then text_ru else text_en end from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_name and lang = :lang) as name,
  (select case when :lang = 'RU' then text_ru else text_en end from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_color and lang = :lang) as color,
  (select case when :lang = 'RU' then text_ru else text_en end from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_description and lang = :lang) as description
from products p;
```

(If you added a third language, you would have to re-write this query and all others.)

One record per language:

```
select
  (select text from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_name and lang = :lang) as name,
  (select text from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_color and lang = :lang) as color,
  (select text from i18n where id = p.id_i18n_description and lang = :lang) as description
from products p;
```

You could also write a stored procedure in this case:

```
select
  i18n_text(id_i18n_name, :lang) as name,
  i18n_text(id_i18n_color, :lang) as color,
  i18n_text(id_i18n_description, :lang) as description
from products;
```

This has the charm of good readability and you could define a default language as a fallback inside the procedure for the case no entry for the desired language can be found.

So for ease of use I would recommend a text table with one text column and the language ID as part of the primary key. As mentioned, I don't expect a big impact performancewise as you are always accessing i18n records by primary key anyway.

So the answer is: One record per text, not two columns. You would lose all dynamic with a column per language. And it is still *one* table, only *two* records. (The "group" is just that there are two records for one I18N ID.) You may want an additional table for the languages (EN = English, RU = Russian, etc.) though.

```
Table I18N

ID  LANG  TEXT
1   EN    Vodka
1   RU    ?????
2   EN    Rum
2   RU    ...

Primary Key = ID + LANG
```